# The loss plot and the criteria for determining whether it converges

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have been running a keras u-net implementation with tensorflow as backend. In the experiment, I run 60 epochs. The loss plot is shown as following, can I assume that the program has converged? Looks to me that the loss does not change significantly.

This is the code related to defining optimizer and launching the training process.

```
  optimizer = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005, nesterov=False)
  autoencoder.compile(loss=customized_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=   [customized_dice])
   nb_epoch = 60
   batch_size = 32
   model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

[image]

Comment: Is this training or validation loss?  If validation, this doesn't seem even close to converging, you would need to run a lot longer.  Also try a higher learning rate

Comment: Hi, I think it is the training loss. I included the code related to defining the optimizer and launching the training. Should you have any comments, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: we need to know which loss is this to help you out. it seems to me this is the cost loss in your model. which helps u to identify confidence and not convergence or accuracy. You might have over fitting, to this limit you need to plot training and validation loss and not the cost.

Comment: Hi Feras, I was using the dice_coefficient discussed here at https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation  . I used segnet instead of u-net. Besides, how to get the training loss. The training output looks like this Epoch 2/60
4375/4375 [==============================] - 821s - loss: 0.7062- acc: 0.9731
Is this loss the training loss or cost loss?

Comment: Hi Feras, can you elaborate more on training loss. In the Keras document, I only see the options to print out cost(loss), accuracy and val_loss. I did not see the item specially named as training losss. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is converging - the initial convergence is fast, then it slows down - that's normal, it can slow down a lot and still improve meaningfully. Sixty epochs may or may not be a long time depending on the number of parameters in your network and the amount of training data.  You want essentially no downward trend over a significant amount of epochs before you decide it is converged.

A pretty good rule of thumb may be something like "number of epochs since lowest loss was seen > total number of epochs / 4".

A separate question is whether it is overtraining.  You need to look at validation loss for that.  Hold back 1/10 or 1/5 of the data from training and use that for validation, when validation loss starts increasing consistently then you're overtraining.

Comment: Is there any suggested value for the hyper-parameters, such as how many epochs?

Comment: The "epochs since the lowest loss was seen > total number of epochs / 4" seems a bit drastic. If you assume the loss acts as a random walk once converged, it should never be more than sqrt(epochs) since last time you saw a minimum...